# How do I update a passed-be-reference struct inside a function?

Tags: c++, struct, pass-by-reference

I have some trouble with passing objects back and forth by reference through functions.

The following example shows a struct, a fixed array variable based on that struct (These I cant change).

I want to create a function that takes an input of a single struct element, blnFindIntersection(). Values are retrieved from that struct during the function. However, at the end of that function, I want to return that struct with a different element and values, so my main application can use the updated struct.

It's another 'by reference' problem I guess, and I just can't get my head around it... Am I doing it right? Am I doing it wrong? How should/could I do what I want this?

```
const int maxobjects = 100 ; 
EXTERN int numobjects ; 
EXTERN struct object {
  shape type ; 
  float size ;
  float position[4] ; 
  float this[4] ; 
  float that[4] ; 
  mat4 transform ; 
  //... etc more values

} objects[maxobjects] ;


bool blnFindIntersection(object &objIntersection)
 //...
 for(int o=0;o<numobjects;o++) {
  obj = &(objects[o]); 
  //... More code, including value retrieval on objIntersection

  //Help here.... Dont know what to do to return the object with updated values from obj..
  objIntersection = &(objects[o]);
  objIntersection = &(obj);
  objIntersection = obj;
 }
}


int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
 object * objNearest;
 bool intersect = false;
 objNearest = &(objects[0]); 

 //... objNearest-> is being used

 intersect = blnFindIntersection(objNearest);

 //... the updated objNearest-> is being used here

 return 0;
}
```

Comment: what would possess you to choose the variable name `o` to be an array index...

Comment: Can you explain what the `objIntersection =` lines are trying to do? Also, what is `obj` ?

Comment: If your function makes changes to `objIntersection` then those changes are also made to `*objNearest` in main (since those designate the same object);  your text seems to suggest you actually do not want to pass by reference  - you want to pass by value, and return by value

Comment: @RedAlert: ahahah yes, +1 for that one. Thats legacy code from before me. Totally agreed with you on that one!
MattMcNabb: That *is* the part that I'm not getting on what to do. If I return by value, does that mean I have to change the function return bool to a return struct? I can see that it may work (though it may make the function less structured or ill-fitting with other functions), can you give an example?

Comment: @FlorianMertens it seems that you are working on some object 'obj' and in end you want to reflect changes in that to 'objIntersection'. You should use object copy constructor for copying values of other objects of type object to objIntersection.

Comment: Im a bit shy of using that, it sounds like I have to add another header file when I was told that no additional header files are needed, it sounds like you want me to kill a problem of a bee with an elephant. How about something like passing the integer obj index by reference? Isn't that easier?